# js file is not including in a theme in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I have created a plugin, it is working fine. Now I have changed my theme of wordpress ( created my own theme ). The problem is that the js file in the plugin is not including when the theme is my theme. The js file is including in other themes. what should I do to solve this problem.

I have used the below code in plugins first page to load the Jquery

```
add_action('init', 'register_script');
function register_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery', plugins_url('/js/bootstrap.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom_jquery1', plugins_url('/js/jquery.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_script( 'cust_pluginjs1', plugins_url('/js/pluginjs.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '2.5.1' );
    wp_register_style( 'new_style', plugins_url('/css/style.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_register_style( 'new_style1', plugins_url('/css/bootstrap.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_register_style( 'new_style2', plugins_url('/css/font-awesome.css', __FILE__), false, '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_localize_script( 'cust_pluginjs1', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_style');

function enqueue_style(){
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('custom_jquery1');
   wp_enqueue_script('cust_pluginjs1');
   wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style' );
   wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style1' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'new_style2' );
}
```

The Jquery used in the .js file is

```
function domainsort(type)
{
  // jQuery.post('http://localhost/wptest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',data )
    jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: myAjax.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'sortfn',
                    sortId: type,

                },

                success:function(data){
                    if(data){
                     jQuery(".tablenpage").html(data);
                    }

                },
                error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Do you have the Jquery library loaded in functions.php?

Comment: @KeesSonnema i have loaded Jquery in plugin's first page. I will update the question with that code.

Comment: Have you tried this: `if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {

    // alert something.

}`

Comment: No but in firebug its showing ReferenceError: domainsort is not defined

Comment: The js and css files included in both theme and plugin are same except this this pluginjs.js file. but the plugin is working fine in all other themes

Comment: This could be anything, but I'm digging the `ReferenceError: domainsort is not defined` now.

Comment: does the above mentioned code are correct?

Comment: Have a look at this http://matthewruddy.com/using-jquery-with-wordpress/

Comment: How can i get the ajaxurl in script?

Comment: Which script do you mean?

Comment: I have coped the function domainsort() to the plugins first page as script then it was showing error myAjax is not defined then I changed the url in ajax as  'http://localhost/wptest/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php' then it was working how can i get the ajaxurl. if i get it i can solve the problem. plz help me to solve this

Comment: Maybe this helps http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0):

You are totally registering/enqueueing wrong here. You are registering your scripts in a function which you hook to `init`, and then you enqueue them in another function and hooking that to `wp_enqueue_scripts`

You should have your `wp_register_script()` and `wp_enqueue_script()` in the same function, and that function should then be hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts`

**EDIT**

You must never use the `init` hook to enqueue scripts or styles. The proper hook to use is `wp_enqueue_scripts`